# How can I use number generated from python in the bash command in the same script?

Tags: python-3.x, bash

```py
import os
define_range=input("Enter a range: ")
os.system("gmx trjcat define_range")
```

Here, I want to use bash command but want to insert input generated using python programming. But I do not have idea how to do that. Can you help me?

Comment: Make sure to sanitize that input, you probably don't want someone to be able to input `3 5 |rm *` or something like that (even if the permissions are only those of the current user, that would still not be nice)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.format` to pass on the required input to the command.

```py
import os
define_range=input("Enter a range: ")
os.system("gmx trjcat {}".format(define_range))
```

Comment: Or, if you are using more or less modern version of Python (>=5.6), you could use f-strings: `os.system(f"gmx trjcat {define_range}")`

Answer (score 0):

you can insert python code in bash script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Hello world!'

python -c "
import os
define_range=input("Enter a range: ")
os.system("gmx trjcat define_range")
"
```